# Удалить БД из PostgreSQL через PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

Есть ли возможность написать скрипт на php который удалит PostgreSQL базу данных?
Другими словами как написать `DROP DATABASE [ IF EXISTS ] name` из php?

Comment: Да собственно так и написать... серверу пофиг, откуда он получает текст команды - лишь бы права были на запрошенное действие: *DROP DATABASE ... It can only be executed by the **database owner**. Also, it cannot be executed while you or anyone else **are connected** to the target database.*

Comment: При создании подключения (pg_connect) я должен указать наименование базы или это необязательно? Как должен выглядеть мой $connStr в pg_connect($connStr) для возможности выполнить эту команду? Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, это возможно и ничем не отличается от любых других SQL запросов.

Необходимы права на удаляемую БД - необходимо быть её владельцем или быть суперпользователем.

Необходимо, чтобы к этой БД никто не был подключен. Убить все активные соединения к базе можно запросом:

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) 
from pg_stat_activity
where datname = 'имя базы';
```

Последний момент может несколько озадачить - как сделать запрос, если соединений с нужной базой быть не должно, но при подключении к PostgreSQL обязательно указывать имя базы сразу. Необходимо подключиться к любой другой базе и оттуда делать `drop database`, эта команда глобальна для всего экземпляра PostgreSQL. В частности, можно подключиться к служебной базе `template1`

Comment: Последний момент меня как раз и озадачил. Большое спасибо за ответ - буду пробовать.